# Path variable contains a period

Tags: environment-variables

I set my environment variable Path to the following
D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin

But when I check it in the Windows command prompt, it outputs this:
PATH=D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;.;

My question: why did a period get added to the end, and what is its meaning?

Answer (score 1):

A `.` means the "current working directory", which is added by default. Thus if you have a program with that name in the current working directory it will look there at the end.

Answer (score 0):

It's a separate path to follow: "this (current) directory". For non-privileged users, it's common to add . to the Path so that you can just type the name of a command or program in your current directory and have it work. Are you saying that Path was *empty* before, and someone/something added . to the Path after you *only* added your Java path?

Answer (score 0):

the period means the current directory!